# Knowing the symbols positions out of a stopping angle

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, 3d

I have a 3D Slot Reel, that I'm trying to simulate a 3D Slot Machine. I have 3D Cylinder that is composed out of 36 meshes ( symbols ) as shown in the figure. There are only 12 symbols, and I'm repeating it 3 times around the cylinder.

When the reel is spinning, I can get the stopping angle, but giving the above information, I would like to change the 3 symbols, that are behind the three symbols which will be appeared to the viewer or the player.
My problem is, I can not find the symbol or the meshes indices, at any desired stop angle when its spinning at any time

[image]

Comment: This post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910882/simulating-slot-machine-cylinder seems to have a bit more information, but I still think we're missing something. Your other post mentions that the cylinder has been "textured randomly at initialization". What does this mean?

Comment: I mean that there are 36 meshes ( textured randomly from 1 - > 12 ) three times to form 36 meshes, with 36 symbols, random from 1 > 12. This is at start up, when the game starts.

Answer (score 1):

You have the angle and need to find the symbols? I may misunderstand, but if that's what you need then in 360 degrees you have 36 symbols - that's 10 degrees each. So given the current angle of the cylinder, if you divide by 10 then you have the symbol number; do a modulo 12 after that since there are only 12 symbols, repeated

answer = (angle / 10) % 12

This gives you the central symbol. The symbol above that is (answer+11)%12 and the symbol below that is (answer+1)%12.

This seems too simple, I must be missing something.

edit: thanks to beaker for pointing out I was taking the wrong modulo.

Comment: so this gives what index ? the first index ? 
The problem is the wheel can stop spinning at any time, and hence at any angle, so I must know the three symbols that will be infront of the viewer, to change the symbols before them :/ That's really my problem

Comment: So I really need to get the indices of the symbols, that at any stopping, get those indcies that are behind the 3 symbols that will be infront of the viewer.

Comment: I think you meant modulo 12 since there are 12 unique symbols.

Comment: @beaker There are 12 unique symbols, but they are repeated 3 times all over the cylinder, so a total of 36 symbols. but I have 36 meshes that hold all those 36 symbols. I want to know what is the mesh index at the giving angle :/

Comment: @Mahmoud Then don't use the modulus. Just use `angle/10`.

Comment: @beaker +1 I tried this. There was a stopping angle 347/10. 34 which maps to mesh 34, at which symbol, it doesn't matter, but now the reel stopped at mesh 11 instead not mesh 34.

Comment: @Mahmoud Which mesh corresponds to a stopping angle of 0? What about 180? (I'm assuming these are all in degrees...)

Comment: Meshs 25, 26, 27 corrsponds to angle of 0 at reset. 180 didn't test

Comment: it worked, but some times the angles are not from 0 to 360, the wheel sometimes spin so much that the angles get to 700

Comment: @Mahmoud larger than 360 isn't a problem since we have the modulo there that already takes care of that.

Comment: Is it possible to define a critical angle ( red line ), where If the symbol before 1 in the picture, is going to pass it ?  How would I calculate it ?